# Validating ConsumerRecord value in KafkaListener

Tags: spring-kafka

I was wondering how I can validated the value of `ConsumerRecord` in `KafkaListener`. I have see example of validating Java Object itself with `@Payload` and `@Valid` however curious how we can on `ConsumerRecord`.

```
@KafkaListener(id="validated", topics = "annotated35", errorHandler = "validationErrorHandler",
      containerFactory = "kafkaJsonListenerContainerFactory")
public void validatedListener(@Payload @Valid ValidatedClass val) {
    ...
}
```

My listener

```
@KafkaListener(id="validate-research", topics = "annotated35", containerFactory = "kafkaJsonListenerContainerFactory")
public void validatedListenerResearch(ConsumerRecord<String, MyObject> myRecord) {
    MyObject myObject = myRecord.value();
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can implement a custom `Validator` to deal with `ConsumerRecord` and its value and inject it according to the doc you took an example from, but there is another trick. Just do this with your method:

```
@KafkaListener(id="validate-research", topics = "annotated35", containerFactory = "kafkaJsonListenerContainerFactory")
public void validatedListenerResearch(ConsumerRecord<String, MyObject> myRecord, @Payload @Valid MyObject myValue) {
```

I mean just add an extra argument to the method with `@Valid` even if you are going to ignore it in the method body.

Comment: So I cant do `public void validatedListenerResearch(@Payload @Valid ConsumerRecord<String, MyObject> myRecord)`

Comment: You can but, as Artem said, you would need a custom validator to unwrap the `value()` from the CR and validate that.